# DoExpressCheckoutPayment response with PaymentStatus None

Tags: paypal

In the live environment we are seeing responses from DoExpressCheckoutPayment where the PaymentStatus is None/Null. The response has Ack set to Success so this would normally imply a valid payment (combined with a PaymentStatus of Completed), however these payments are ultimately declined. We are using the PayPal NuGet packages under ASP.NET.

My question is does None/Null imply that we need to execute another API call in order to get the actual status? Do we just call DoExpressCheckoutPayment again or do we call GetTransactionDetails? Ultimately if the status cannot be determined within a checkout pipeline then we would need to reject the payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payment status should not be null it should be completed or pending. Any other status usually means that the payment did not complete or there was an error. One way to make certain that the transaction is completed is to send a GetTransactionDetails API Call or a TransactionSearch API Call.

From the PayPal developer Site here is the Transaction Search: 
[How to Do a Transaction Search](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/)

```
Request 
-------
Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
HTTP method: POST
POST data:
USER=merchant_user_name
&PWD=merchant_password
&SIGNATURE=merchant_signature
&METHOD=TransactionSearch
&STARTDATE=2012-01-01T05:38:48Z    #Start date of the time range for the   search
&ENDDATE=2012-01-31T05:38:48Z     #End date of the time range for the search
&VERSION=94

Response
--------
L_TIMESTAMP0=2012%2d01%2d11T06%3a39%3a13Z
...
&L_TIMEZONE0=GMT
...
&L_TYPE0=Payment
...
&L_EMAIL0=test_user%40x%2ecom
...
&L_NAME0=TestName%20Q
...
&L_TRANSACTIONID0=9XJ88717E86951234
...
&L_STATUS0=Completed
...
&L_AMT0=0%2e11
...
&L_CURRENCYCODE0=USD
...
&L_FEEAMT0=0%2e00
...
&L_NETAMT0=0%2e11
...
&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d10%2d01T17%3a55%3a54Z
&ACK=Success
...
```

Comment: Can GetTransactionDetails be called immediately after the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call?

Comment: Yes, you can call GetTransactionDetails right after the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from a high level perspective, we are treating this type of payment status as "Open" or "Pending"  internally.
Once we receive the notification from the IPN, we can really know if the payment was successfully or not (payment_status=Completed in the notification).